# How can I print base variables in Gurobi using java?

Tags: java, variables, printing, model, gurobi

I have to print 1 if the variable is a based variable, otherwise 0. I try this but it doesn't work:

```
for(GRBVar var : model.getVars()){      
        double v = var.get(DoubleAttr.RC);
            if(v == 0) System.out.println(var.get(StringAttr.VarName) + " : 1");
            else System.out.println(var.get(StringAttr.VarName) + " : 0");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the basis status of a variable, you just need to query its [VBasis attribute](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/vbasis.html):

> The status of a given variable in the current basis. Possible values are 0 (basic), -1 (non-basic at lower bound), -2 (non-basic at upper bound), and -3 (super-basic).